# Design mode is not showing any elements in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, adobe, dreamweaver

I am using Adobe Dreamweaver to create HTML, I have few buttons on a html page, but when i added few more buttons in code mode, design more is not showing any buttons and elements, but I am able to view the output. Is there any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you want to hear Rajesh, but DW's design mode is simply terrible and always has been. You are far better working solely in code view, and using the browser to monitor progress.

You can develop locally using something like XAMPP, and hook the browser up with LiveReload and you'll see instant changes reflecting the code, rendering DW's design view pretty much useless.

Comment: Was this answer any use to you?